# Asking questions in an array

Tags: vb.net, arrays, arraylist

Hey all i am having a hard time coming up with the correct flow for a question form. Lets say i have 6 questions. I define them like this:

```
 Dim firstStart As Boolean = True
 Dim totalQs As Integer = 0
 Dim currentQ As Integer = 0
 Dim theAnswers() As String
 Dim theQuestions() As String = {"Please scan barcode 1 then press NEXT", "" & _
                                "Please scan barcode 1 then press NEXT", "" & _
                                "Please scan barcode 1 then press NEXT", "" & _
                                "Please scan barcode 1 then press NEXT", "" & _
                                "Please scan barcode 1 then press NEXT", "" & _
                                "Please scan barcode 1 then press COMPLETE"}
```

The Next/Complete button code looks like this:

```
Private Sub cmdNextFinish_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As             System.EventArgs) Handles cmdNextFinish.Click
   Call theQs(currentQ)
End Sub
```

The form_load looks like this:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Call theQs(0)
End Sub
```

And now the question setup looks like this:

```
Private Sub theQs(ByRef theQNum As Integer)
    If firstStart = True And theQNum = 0 Then
        firstStart = False
        totalQs = (theQuestions.Length)
        ReDim theAnswers(totalQs)
        lblQ.Text = theQuestions(0)
        cmdNextFinish.Enabled = True
        cmdNextFinish.Text = "NEXT"
        Call buttons(theQNum)
        txtNumber.Text = ""
        txtNumber.MaxLength = theQuestionTextboxLimits(theQNum)
        txtNumber.Focus()
    ElseIf theQNum = 0 Then 'ANSWERING THE FIRST QUESTION
        theAnswers(currentQ) = "-" & txtNumber.Text

        If currentQ <> totalQs Then
            currentQ = currentQ + 1
            lblQ.Text = theQuestions(currentQ)

            If (totalQs - currentQ) = 0 Then
                cmdNextFinish.Text = "Complete"
            Else
                cmdNextFinish.Text = "NEXT"
            End If

            txtNumber.Text = ""
            txtNumber.MaxLength = theQuestionTextboxLimits(theQNum)
            txtNumber.Focus()
            Call buttons(currentQ)
        Else
            'Call writeXMLFile()
            MsgBox("exited")
        End If
    ElseIf theQNum = 1 Then 'ANSWERING THE SECOND QUESTION
        theAnswers(currentQ) = txtNumber.Text

        If theQNum <> totalQs Then
            currentQ = currentQ + 1
            lblQ.Text = theQuestions(currentQ)

            If (totalQs - currentQ) = 0 Then
                cmdNextFinish.Text = "Complete"
            Else
                cmdNextFinish.Text = "NEXT"
            End If

            txtNumber.Text = ""
            txtNumber.MaxLength = theQuestionTextboxLimits(theQNum)
            txtNumber.Focus()
            Call buttons(currentQ)
        Else
            'Call writeXMLFile()
            MsgBox("exited")
        End If
    ElseIf theQNum = 2 Then 'ANSWERING THE THIRD QUESTION
        theAnswers(currentQ) = txtNumber.Text

        If theQNum <> totalQs Then
            currentQ = currentQ + 1
            lblQ.Text = theQuestions(currentQ)

            If (totalQs - currentQ) = 0 Then
                cmdNextFinish.Text = "Complete"
            Else
                cmdNextFinish.Text = "NEXT"
            End If

            txtNumber.Text = ""
            txtNumber.MaxLength = theQuestionTextboxLimits(theQNum)
            txtNumber.Focus()
            Call buttons(currentQ)
        Else
            'Call writeXMLFile()
            MsgBox("exited")
        End If
    ElseIf theQNum = 3 Then 'ANSWERING THE FORTH QUESTION
        theAnswers(currentQ) = txtNumber.Text

        If theQNum <> totalQs Then
            currentQ = currentQ + 1
            lblQ.Text = theQuestions(currentQ)

            If (totalQs - currentQ) = 0 Then
                cmdNextFinish.Text = "Complete"
            Else
                cmdNextFinish.Text = "NEXT"
            End If

            txtNumber.Text = ""
            txtNumber.MaxLength = theQuestionTextboxLimits(theQNum)
            txtNumber.Focus()
            Call buttons(currentQ)
        Else
            'Call writeXMLFile()
            MsgBox("exited")
        End If
    ElseIf theQNum = 4 Then 'ANSWERING THE FIFTH QUESTION
        theAnswers(currentQ) = txtNumber.Text

        If theQNum <> totalQs Then
            currentQ = currentQ + 1
            lblQ.Text = theQuestions(currentQ)

            If (totalQs - currentQ) = 0 Then
                cmdNextFinish.Text = "Complete"
            Else
                cmdNextFinish.Text = "NEXT"
            End If

            txtNumber.Text = ""
            txtNumber.MaxLength = theQuestionTextboxLimits(theQNum)
            txtNumber.Focus()
            Call buttons(currentQ)
        Else
            'Call writeXMLFile()
            MsgBox("exited")
        End If
    ElseIf theQNum = 5 Then 'ANSWERING THE SIXTH QUESTION
        theAnswers(currentQ) = txtNumber.Text

        If theQNum <> totalQs Then
            currentQ = currentQ + 1
            lblQ.Text = theQuestions(currentQ)

            If (totalQs - currentQ) = 0 Then
                cmdNextFinish.Text = "Complete"
            Else
                cmdNextFinish.Text = "NEXT"
            End If

            txtNumber.Text = ""
            txtNumber.MaxLength = theQuestionTextboxLimits(theQNum)
            txtNumber.Focus()
            Call buttons(currentQ)
        Else
            'Call writeXMLFile()
            MsgBox("exited")
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

I seem to be getting confused because when it gets to the 5th question it gives me an error of **Index was outside the bounds of the array.** on the line of

```
lblQ.Text = theQuestions(currentQ)
```

for **theQNum = 5**

I know its on the 5th question but the array does not go up to 6.

What am i doing wrong here (or overthinking something simple)

Thanks,

David

**UPDATE GOT IT**

```
 Private theQNum As Integer

 Sub Start
   theQNum =0
   SetupNextQuestion
 End Sub

 Sub SetupNextQuestion
   txtNumber.Text = ""
   lblQuestion.Text = theQuestions(theQNum)

   If theQNum = (theQuestions.Length - 1) Then
      cmdNextFinish.Text = "Complete"
   Else
      cmdNextFinish.Text = "NEXT"
   End If

 End Sub

 Sub cmdNextFinish_Click
   theAnswers(theQNum) = txtNumber.Text

   'Check if this is a finish
   theQNum += 1
   If theQNum >= theQuestions.Length Then
      'Call writeXMLFile()
       MsgBox("exited")
   Else 
       SetupNextQuestion
   End If
 End Sub
```

David

Answer (score 1):

These lines:

```
If theQNum <> totalQs Then
            currentQ = currentQ + 1
            lblQ.Text = theQuestions(currentQ)
```

Which are inside the If for your `ElseIf theQNum = 5 Then` are what is causing you to get out of bounds.  But the problem is much earlier in your if.  You start with

```
If firstStart = True And theQNum = 0 Then
       ' Code here
ElseIf theQNum = 0 Then 'ANSWERING THE FIRST QUESTION
       'More code here that doesn't get called
```

That ElseIf theQNum = 0 won't be called on first run, because the first part of the if is true.  And in that first bit of code when firstStart is true, you don't increment currentQ so next time this sub is called firststart is false, but currentQ is still 0. The root of your issue.

The simple fix is to increment your currentQ inside that first bit of your if and to always set the label text **BEFORE** you increment currentQ.  And don't increment it when you are at your last question. That way currentQ will never get out of range.

Answer (score 0):

Arrays start from 0 onwards. SO, your first question is at index 0  & sixth question is at index 5 in array. If you increase the index beforehand for last question the index becomes 6 which has no value.

Comment: Still gives the error of **Index was outside the bounds of the array** That number needs to be 1 ahead since theQNum its on (say 0) needs to load up the next question (1) after the user presses NEXT.

Comment: why are you increasing the value of currentQ. The value of currentQ will become 6. The array starts from 0 onwards that means the sixth question is theQuestions(5)

Comment: Because thats what is populated when the button is pressed so the NEXT button would be incrested by 1 each go around until it got the the last question where COMPLETE would be on the button.